# Recitation of the Quran without understanding Arabic

Tags: quran, quran-recitation

I was brought up a Muslim and taught that recitation of the Quran in Arabic (although I didn't understand Arabic and still don't) bears great "sawab". I haven't been able to find anything regarding this anywhere in Ahadith or the Quran. What does Islam really say about this? Is it true or it is just a bidd'a (or biddat)?

Technically, it's a waste of time to read the Arabic without understanding a thing of it, isn't it? So what's the logical thing to do in this case according to Islamic teachings?

Comment: reading Quran is not reading only Arabic. God gives any sawab to anyone he wish. at least this is a test.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is given in a *hadith* of the Prophet (saws):

> Narrated Muhammad bin Ka'b Al-Qurazi:
>
> "I heard 'Abdullah bin Mas'ud saying: 'The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "[Whoever recites a letter] from Allah's Book, then he receives the reward from it, and the reward of ten the like of it. I do not say that Alif Lam Mim is a letter, but Alif is a letter, Lam is a letter and Mim is a letter." ([Source](http://sunnah.com/urn/731520))

Of course the better thing by far is to recite with understanding (whether through knowledge of the language or through a translation). The fact remains however that this is Allah's Speech and He has put *barakah* in its recitation alone, even without reflection and pondering.

Answer (score 3):

Quran itself describes its purpose it is revealed so that it is a source of guidance and [people ponder over it](http://quran.com/38/29). Reciting it, without understanding defeats the basic purpose of it.

We should make Quran a center of our knowledge and actions.